# Set interval ajax request

Tags: javascript

Hello guys i have a problem with `SetInterval` i've try using it like this to refresh my request but it's not working

```
setInterval(test, 10000);
$.get("https://ipinfo.io",
    function test(response) {
        console.log(response.ip, response.country);
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
        var creatediv = function(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(s1);
            div.appendChild(s2);
            return div;
        }
        var createspan = function(value) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerText = value;
            return span;
        }
        body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Your IP adress:  '), createspan(response.ip)))
        body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Your City:  '), createspan(response.city)))
        body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Country:  '), createspan(response.country)))
        body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Postal Code:  '), createspan(response.postal)))


    }, "jsonp")
```

Comment: Why not put the `get` inside the `test` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$.get()` inside your interval callback:

```js
setInterval(test, 1000);

function test() {
  $.get("https://ipinfo.io",
    function test(response) {
      console.log(response.ip, response.country);
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
      var creatediv = function(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(s1);
        div.appendChild(s2);
        return div;
      }
      var createspan = function(value) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerText = value;
        return span;
      }
      body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Your IP adress:  '), createspan(response.ip)))
      body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Your City:  '), createspan(response.city)))
      body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Country:  '), createspan(response.country)))
      body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Postal Code:  '), createspan(response.postal)))


    }, "jsonp");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's working , but i have one more question how can i rewrite those span ? now spans clone on my entire spans  everytime when set interval pop

Comment: Define a element wrapping the output and clean it before appending the new elements to it (using `.innerHTML = ''`)

Comment: Ty mate . i iwll try it :D

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have is that your refresh will never refresh.   Presumably, you want to fetch the latest data from ipinfo every second, then update your display to show that information.
The `test()` function as it's set up contains only the logic needed to update the display - not to fetch data.

The next issue is that he `test()` function you're trying to call in setInterval is created as a closure function, which isn't available in the global scope.
You can define `test()` on its own to correct this.

Combining those two fixes will allow setInterval to call the server and manipulate the page.

```
function test() {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io",
        function (response) {
            console.log(response.ip, response.country);
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
            var creatediv = function(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.appendChild(s1);
                div.appendChild(s2);
                return div;
            }
            var createspan = function(value) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerText = value;
                return span;
            }
            body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Your IP adress:  '), createspan(response.ip)))
            body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Your City:  '), createspan(response.city)))
            body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Country:  '), createspan(response.country)))
            body.appendChild(creatediv(createspan('Postal Code:  '), createspan(response.postal)))
        }, "jsonp")
}
```